# How to apply a rename command to all subfolders in powershell?

Tags: powershell, rename, batch-rename

I am new to powershell and I am having a hard time applying this one command to all of the subfolders I have. I have used:

```
ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "ALL",""}
```

And this works for only the one subfolder that I am in. This takes the ALL out of the files names as that is not needed for my purposes. How would I go about applying this command to all of the subfolders so I don't have to go in manually and apply them one at a time. So far, I have tried

```
dir -recurse ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "ALL",""}
```

And this *ran* but didn't do anything to any of the files. I tried a few variations of this as well, but they did not compile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `dir -recurse ls` => `dir -recurse`

Comment: Be aware that your approach is not safe for all possible file names. Conflicts will arise for names like `filenameALL` and `fileALLname`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `dir -recurse ls`

`dir` and `ls`<sup>[1]</sup> are both *aliases* of PowerShell's [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) cmdlet, so you need:

- *either* `dir -recurse`
- *or* `ls -recurse`
- *or* - the best choice if you want to use an *alias*<sup>[2]</sup>  - `gci -recurse`
- *or*, finally, using the full cmdlet name, `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`

<sup>To see all aliases that are defined for `Get-ChildItem`, run  `Get-Alias -Definition Get-ChildItem`.</sup>

Additionally, to limit processing to *files*, add the `-File` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'ALL' }
```

<sup>I'm using `'...'` quoting instead of `"..."` quoting for conceptual clarity, given that the string's content is to be used *verbatim* (no string interpolation needed). Also, omitting the replacement-string operand of the `-replace` operator *defaults* to `''` (the empty string), so it can be omitted.</sup>

Note: The [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator is case-*insensitive* by default, as PowerShell generally is. If you want to match `ALL` only in all-uppercase, use the case-*sensitive* variant of the operator, 
`-creplace`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> this *ran*, but didn't do anything to any of the files

- `ls` in your `dir -recurse ls` command was positionally bound to `Get-ChildItem`'s 
  `-Path` parameter.
- Because of the **highly unfortunate behavior of `-Path` in combination with `-Recurse`**, described in [GitHub issue #5699](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5699), *no* error occurred, despite there (presumably) being no file or subdirectory literally named `ls`.

  - In effect, `Get-ChildItem` looked for an file or directory named `ls` *on all levels of the subdirectory hierarchy* and, in the absence of any, produced *no output*, i.e. amounted to a *quiet no-op*.
  - While in your case this behavior amounted to *obscure failure*, in the worst-case scenario it can be *destructive*, as discussed in the linked GitHub issue.

---

<sup>[1] on *Windows*; on Unix-like platforms, `ls` refers to the platform-native `/bin/ls` utility.</sup>

<sup>[2] This is the best choice, because it doesn't use the name of another shell's or platform's similar, but syntactically different command or utility. The name `gci` is formed according to PowerShell's *own* naming conventions, where `g` is the official alias abbreviation of the `Get`, one of the [approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

A loop through the piped output would be what you are after.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object{Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Name -replace "ALL","")}
```

This will apply the `Rename-Item` *for each* line in the piped output.

Comment: Sorry for the redundancy, but in this case I would not change the FullName or -NewName commands, I would just leave that as it is? Or would I change fullname to the "paths" full name so the computer knows where to go and change things?

Comment: `Rename-Item` is expecting the path of the file it is working on, which is where the `$_.FullName` comes into play within the loop. If you want to change the location that the renaming command takes place, provide the `Get-ChildItem` a `-Path` parameter.

Comment: Piping _directly_ to `Rename-Item` with a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) is always preferable to a `ForEach-Object` solution - both in terms of conceptual elegance and particularly in terms of performance. It is what @Cole attempted, but fell short due to accidentally using _both_ `dir` and `ls`.